# How to Set up a new Azure MVC Project in VS2013 with Roles?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-roles

I am new to Windows Azure Developement and VS2013. I was trying to follow a VS2010 tutorial from pluralsight.com where the presenter creates a new `MVC 4 Web Application Visual C#` in Windows Azure. When prompted he adds a `Worker Role` and a `Web Role` to the Application when setting up the project.

Since this tutorial was done, Windows Azure seems to have changed alot as well as VS project setups.

How do i do this in VS 2013 ?

I have downloaded the Windows Azure SDK 2.2 for VS2013 I am not seeing the same workflow for setting up the project . .

Can someone please help me ?

[image: solution explorer MVC 4 Web Application VS 2013]

Here is what the MVC project solution explorer looks like, but when i right click to add there is no `Roles` items to add. How can I do this?

For some reason even after installing the Azure SDK this is all that shows up. Does this mean that the SDK is not Installed Correctly?

[image]

This is what pops up

[image]

**UPDATE**

I reinstalled the Windows Azure SDK for VS 2013 and now the Cloud Service option is showing up. Looks like you cannot run a VS2013 Express Version side by side with a Premium VS 2013 Version.

[image]

Another thing to note here was that I had to hit tools, and connect to my Windows Azure Account even after logging in with my Microsoft ID using Tools -> Connect to Windows Azure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a cloud project. At the solution level, FILE >> NEW PROJECT >> Templates >> Visual c# >> Cloud >> Windows Azure Cloud Service.

[image]

Then, Visual C# >> ASP.NET Web Role

[image]

Comment: Can you please look at the updated post above. I am not sure if windows Azure SDK is installed correctly.

Comment: When i click that to add the Windows SDK it pops up the Web Application Installer and then tells me there is nothing to install. . .

Comment: something is definitely not installed correctly.  Make sure you close and relaunch VS2013 as well.

Comment: I removed the Web VS2013 express. I am trying to uninstall the current SDK and reinstall it. This does not make much sense to me though since i have already created a windows Azure project and have it connected to my account and running. very confusing

Comment: This works great for me in 2012. Thanks for the Help . I think 2013 is configured wrong. I need to set it up again and try the same thing.

Comment: Okay, so I posted my update above after uninstalling Express VS 2013 and reinstalling the Azure SDK, I can now create the Roles Using this answer. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3):

Since you have an existing ASP.NET MVC project, the easiest way to enable this as a Windows Azure Cloud Service (Web Role) is to do the following:

1. Right click on the ASP.NET MVC project name
2. Select Convert
3. Select "Convert to Windows Azure Cloud Service Project"

Visual Studio will then automatically create a new Windows Azure Cloud Service project in your current solution, and will a new Web Role to the Cloud Service project.

[image: Add a new Windows Azure Cloud Service project]

[image: New Web Role created]

Comment: I am not seeing this. I think there may be an issue with having vs2013 express installed next to vs2013. I am uninstalling that express version and going to reinstall the SDK and see if i can do this.